# ImageMagick: composite one image over second

Tags: php, imagemagick

I have 2 JPEG images:

```
image1.jpg 
image2.jpg
```

Both images have the same width of 1200px.

image1 height is 800px and image2 height is 2000px.

I want to place image1 over image2 and create image3 out of it... so:

```
image1+image2 = image3
```

image3 will contain the 1200x800 section of image 1 and then remaining bottom section will be of image 2.

Comment: @EdChum et al.: Pah-lease! Why are these people who put this question "on hold" thinking that there are *"too many possible answers"* or *"good answers would be too long for this format"*?!? Because they themselves do not understand it?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's easy.

Since you didn't provide (links to) sample images, I first create my own, albeit with 120x80px and 120x200px (instead of 1200x800px and 1200x2000px):

```
 convert -size 120x80 xc:blue img1.jpg
 convert -size 120x200 xc:red img2.jpg
```

Now I place `img1.jpg` over `img2.jpg`:

```
 composite img1.jpg img2.jpg img3.jpg
```

Here are the three images. Left is `img1.jpg`, center is `img2.jpg` and right is `img3.jpg`:

[image: Resulting images from above commands]

### Update

In this case it was that easy because the default `-geometry` setting is `+0+0` which is what you wanted.

In case you want some offset of the overlayed image, you have to add this parameter. For example shift the overlaid image by 20 pixels to the right, and 44 pixels to the bottom:

```
 composite img1.jpg img2.jpg -geometry '-20+44' img3.jpg
```

Result:

[image: Resulting image (right) after shifting the overlaid image]

Comment: wow, worked like anything...  composite img1.jpg img2.jpg img3.jpg